# SSAS Dynamic Security based on user groups

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm new to MDX and I'm looking to configure dynamic security in SSAS based on the role's allowed member set. All I can find on the internet is to link the user to the dimension attribute with a bridge table. However, I would like to have a user group table between the two. A user can belong to one or many user groups and a user group can have access to one or many dimension attributes.

My query looks like this:

```
    SELECT {[Measures].[Sales]} ON COLUMNS,
    EXISTS
        (
         [Stores].[Store].members,
              NonEmpty (
                             [Groups].[GroupDetails].members,
                             (
                                  StrToMember ("[Users].[User].[" + UserName() + "]"),
                                  [Measures].[Bridge users group count]
                             )
                        ), "Bridge Groups Stores Count"
        ) 
ON ROWS FROM [Sales]
```

Since I'm new to MDX, you will understand that my query does not work because of, I assume, the NonEmpty section.

Can anyone please help me toward the right direction?

Comment: What is UserName() returning? A valid member name in the [Users] dimension?